# The conditional expectation in Gambler’s ruin

Tags: probability, self-study, markov-process

Consider the random walk $X_0, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ on state space $S=\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$ with absorbing states $A=\{0,N\}$, and with $P(i,i+1)=p$ and $P(i,i-1)=q$ for all $i \in S \setminus A$, where $p+q=1$ and $p,q>0$.

Let $T:=\inf \left\{n\ge 0:X_{n}\in \left\{0,N \right\}\right\}$ denote the number of steps until the walk is absorbed in either $0$ or $N$.

I don't know why $\mathbb{E}\left\{T\mid X_{1}=k+1\right\}=\mathbb{E} \mathbb\{T | X_0 = k+1\}+1$ for any $k \in S \setminus A$.

---

I can only provide a strict proof that  $$\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}\left\{T\mid X_{1}=k\right\}=\mathbb{E} \mathbb\{T | X_0 = k\}+1,\forall k\in  \left\{1,\cdots,N-1 \right\} \tag{1} 
\end{align}
$$

But I feel the following  equation $(2)$ is not true:

$$\begin{align}
    &\mathbb{E}\left\{T\mid X_{1}=N\right\}=\mathbb{E} \mathbb\{T | X_0 = N\}+1\tag{2} \\\text{since} \quad &\mathbb{E}\left\{T\mid X_{1}=N\right\}=\frac{p\cdot\mathbf{P}(X_0=N-1)}{p\cdot\mathbf{P}(X_0=N-1)+1\cdot\mathbf{P}(X_0=N)}\tag{3}\\\text{and}\quad &\mathbb{E} \mathbb\{T | X_0 = N\}=0\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I think your calculation is right.  The claim you cited (from where?) is incorrect when $k = N - 1$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong:This claim comes from the fourteenth page of the lecture notes (Please refer to the third-to-last and fourth-to-last equations.)https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/past-devel/archive/spring00/archive/lectures/L26.pdf. Thanks for your feedback.